# table Normalization

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, oracle, normalization

I am working on timesheet application and have question on normalization.

I have linked three tables in option-I and in the option-II there is no Group and SubGroup table, just one Activity table.

I like to know which option is better according to the following layout.

[image]

[image]

**ADDED - New Option**

[image]

Comment: To summarize you are asking is it best to use the numbers (int) as a Foreign Key or the actual string.  My answer is that is clearly up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for a solution with one `GROUP` table and one `ACTIVITY` table:

```
GROUP_ID (PK)   PARENT_GROUP_ID (FK)   CODE          NAME
--------------- ---------------------- ------------- ------------
1               (null)                 4             IT ACTIVITIES
2               (null)                 5             ADMINISTRATION
3               (null)                 6             FINANCE
4               (null)                 7             HR
5               1                      4.1           IT ADMIN
6               1                      4.2           IT NETWORK
7               2                      5.1           MEETING


ACTIVITY_ID (PK)   GROUP_ID (FK)  CODE     NAME
------------------ -------------- -------- -----------
1                  5              4.1.1    IT PROC
2                  5              4.1.2    HELPDESK
3                  6              4.2.1    TECHNICAL SUPPORT
(etc)
```

Each table would use an integer surrogate key (running number) for primary key so you don't break referential integrity if you have to change the code for a group or an activity. The foreign key on column `PARENT_GROUP_ID` referrs back to the same table and column `GROUP_ID`.

Using a setup like this makes it *relatively* easy to add more levels in the group hierarchy if that should ever become necessary (and it will, managers always want more detailed reports :-) ). I say relatively easy since you might have to go about updating a lot of the group and activity codes. But you would not have to change (for instance) all timesheets referencing a specific activity since they would be referencing the integer surrogate key.

The same goes for introducing sibling nodes. If you (for instance) need to insert a sub group between 4.2 and 4.3 it will not be too difficult. Just update the code for the *current* 4.3 group to 4.4 and then insert the new group with code 4.3.

Also, this makes it possible to have activities anywhere in the group tree, if that would ever be needed.

Comment: I like this solution, a more flexible version of what I was suggesting.  I like the fact you allow it to support multiple levels.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Please check my new added option and i have updated tables as you mentioned in your last comments. With this new option user will be able to create new groups, subgroups and activities, also activities can be linked to subgroups. What functionality you think is not achievable with my new option as compare to yours?

Comment: With your new option, an activity must always be attached to a sub group. It cannot be directly connected to a parent group. And also with this solution you will not be able to add "sub sub" groups. If it's clear that the group structure will always have two levels and activities must always belong to a sub group, your new option looks fine.

Comment: As per requirements, activity will always be linked to subgroup and can't be connected to main group. I don't think there will be any sub sub group but i am getting clarification on it and will come back on it asap. If there will be a possibility then i agree with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Surely it would be better to have the subgroup refer to the group? then the activity just refers to the subgroup?

Comment: I dont think I have, he said in option 2 there is no group and subgroup tables and in option 1 there are.  As per his diagram.  My point still stands, why is he referring to both the group and subgroup tables when clearly the subgroup should be the one linked to its parent group.

Comment: Maybe - The question is not clearly defined and the sample data between both methods is different.

Comment: The very clearly defined.  My opinion though is that neither are great options and that a modification of option 1 is better.

Comment: I agree.  You want to move Group Code off of the Activity table and onto the SubGroup table... then Option 1 is what I would go with

Comment: Hi Jon, please check my new added option and i have updated tables as you mentioned in your last comments. With this new option user will be able to create new groups, subgroups and activities, also activities can be linked to subgroups. Do you think it is still better to have two tables as mentioned in third answer?

Comment: @user1263981 that would work, however I would actually recommend user1429080's answer above mine now.  The reason for this is it supports more than one level of groups/subgroups.  If however you will only every have this structure and activities will always be part of subgroups, not groups then this is perfectly fine.